# MySQL Add Column that Summarizes data from Another Column

Tags: mysql

I have a column in MySQL table which has 'messy' data stored as text like this:

```
**SIZE**
2
2-5
6-25
2-10
26-100
48
50
```

I want to create a new column "RevTextSize" that rewrites the data in this column to a pre-defined range of values.

```
If Size=2, then "RevTextSize"= "1-5"
If Size=2-5, then "RevTextSize"= "1-5"
If Size=6-25, then "RevTextSize"="6-25" 
...
```

This is easy to do in Excel, SPSS and other such tools, but how can I do it in the MySQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE messy_data ADD revtextsize VARCHAR(30);
```

To populate the column:

```
UPDATE messy_data
   SET revtextsize 
       = CASE 
         WHEN size = '2'     THEN '1-5'
         WHEN size = '2-5'   THEN '1-5'
         WHEN size = '6-25'  THEN '6-25'
         ELSE size
         END
```

This is a brute-force approach, identifying each distinct value of `size` and specifying a replacement.

---

You could use another SQL statement to help you build the CASE expression

```
  SELECT CONCAT('     WHEN size = ''',d.size,'''    THEN ''',d.size,'''') AS stmt
    FROM messy_data d
   GROUP BY d.size
```

Save the result from that into your favorite SQL text editor, and hack away at the replacement values. That would speed up the creation of the CASE expression for the statement you need to run to set the revtextsize column (the first statement).

If you want to build something "smarter", that dynamically evaluates the contents of size and makes an intelligent choice, that would be more involved. If was going to do that, I'd do it in the second statement, generating the CASE expression. I'd prefer to review that, befor I run the update statement. I prefer to have the update statement doing something that's easy to understand and easy to explain what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr() to locate "-" in your string and use SUBSTRING(str, pos, len) to get start & End number. Then Use Between clause to build your Case clause.

Hope this will help in building your solution.

Thanks